# Is it possible to share a delegate, or to re-delegate a protocol's methods to another delegate?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

```
class SuperClass
{
    var delegate : SuperClassDelegate?
}

protocol SuperClassDelegate
{
    func doFirstAction ()
    func doSecondAction ()
}

class SubClass : SuperClass , SuperClassDelegate
{
    override init ()
    {
        super.init()

        self.delegate = self
    }

    func doFirstAction () {}
}

class MyViewController : UIViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad ()
    {
        let c : SubClass = SubClass()
    }

    func doSecondAction ()
    {
        // I want to handle this action in the ViewController
    }
}
```

So I've made a subclass that, for convenience, can act as the superclass delegate. However some of the methods in the superclass delegate are still most appropriately implemented in a view controller, meaning I don't want my subclass to implement these.

Is there a better way I can be dealing with these delegates so I can 'share' the responsibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a multicast delegate. That way multiple objects (the subclass, the ViewController) could be delegates from the caller object. The protocol methods would be optional and then you could choose which class would implement what methods from the protocol.

Alternatively you could just create 2 protocols with 2 delegate references in the caller object. Unless there would be some specific reason you want to use a single protocol.